# How can i create this view?

Tags: android, listview, view, android-custom-view

How Can I draw this view?
......

Comment: use relative layout

Comment: use constraint layout

Answer (score 1):

use relative layout for positioning

use an image button of (X) with no background color and place it in the center
using

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnid" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/(X)image">
</ImageButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have asked 2 question for
1)How Can I draw this xml layout in android?

You should try some xml code and post where you are stuck

2)How to position the (X) button in the center-bottom of the layout.

For this use parent layout as 'Relative Layout' and place you view(let's say you have ImageView) as layout_alignParentBottom = true and layout_centerHorizontal = true. You may refer below code as well.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Testing"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```